Provide GRANT SELECT to view in gold layer without providing access to underlying tables
I have a view in gold layer which has multiple inner and left joins, i have a end user who needs select access to view. I want to provide access to view in gold layer without providing access to underlying tables in databricks. Please help with suggestions.
I tried with providing access to underlying tables, so user can access view data. But this is not the expectations

Are you using Unity catalog or not? Have you tried granting SELECT access to the view and not the underlying tables? The user needs USE access to the catalog and schema.

@AnupamChand
Unity  catalog is not enabled. I already tried to give select access but not given any other access to catalog and schema

Since Unity Catalog is not enabled, I am assuming that Hive Metastore is your governance model.
You will need to ensure that Usage has been provided to the User's security principal on both the catalog level and the schema level that contains the view.
Usage is a privilege that doesn't change any access by default but will allow security principals to have privileges on data contained within the schema/catalog.
For more information on how Hive Metastore works please use this Azure Learn page for Azure Databricks (the same knowledge should apply to standard Databricks also): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/table-acls/object-privileges
